# Superfish menu z-index issue

Tags: html, css

I have a simple layout.

```
<div id="menu" style="height=30px"> </div>
<div id="content"> </div>
```

The superfish menu is in the MENU div. Menu div must be 30px height but so the superfish menu dropdown can't see because does not fit. (Superfish menu is 200px when dropped down)

I try to set z-index to MENU div but it does not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried on [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: i dont really know how to link my JS files, images..etc..

Comment: Just paste the code block in your question, if it's too much trouble setting up a fiddle. Although ideally you should do that.

Comment: i figured out: i have to set z-index plus position:absolute to sf-menu class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` works only with `position:absolute` or `position:relative`.

Comment: yes. z-index plus pos:abs, or position realitve with owerflow:visible.